# Why are things "infectious" but not "infectionate", but you can be "affectionate" but not "affectious"?

Tags: etymology, conjugation, roots

Seems inconsistent, I guess it's because something something Latin?

Comment: Perhaps the CV-ers could suggest a suitable resource to use to investigate this. I can't think of one offhand. Collins gives broad usages for the suffixes, but hardly a full explanation of differences. Indeed, 'globate' and 'globous' (-ous a variant of -ious) are synonyms.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed? I speak English natively but I'm not an English etymology expert or linguistic academic, how am I supposed to get started doing "research" on this?

Comment: You could look up the words in dictionaries and see if they give etymological information? Or google *etymology infectious*? A lot of people seem to ask ChatGPT. (Although I suspect part of the reason that was closed is that the answer is "by accident". [Affectionate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/affectionate) probably comes via French *affectionné*, while [infectious](https://www.etymonline.com/word/infectious) seems to be an English coinage from infection; *infectuous* and *infective* are older, and which persisted is almost definitely a matter of chance.)

Comment: Got it, in the future I will ask ChatGPT instead of using StackExchange.

Comment: I looked up the semantic factors in play with the adjectivising suffixes: **-ious/-ous**: 'characterized by or full of' ... 'added to stems of Latin origin, often with corresponding nouns ending in -ity' [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ious)] and **-ate**: 'possessing; having the appearance or characteristics of ...  of or characteristic of ... having or filled with ... forming adjectives roughly equivalent to corresponding past participles ending in -ed {animate (animated), determinate (determined)}'. But that's as far as I got.